# My Ci db driver not work while i echo Modules::run

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

Hi can anyone could you help me i have problem with my Modules::run function of Module extension of codeigniter whhile i echo modules :: run () in route method the db driver of ci didn't load

my code run like this

i have route page job/view/receptionist to job/receptionist

when i load this route page, i want to echo Modules::run("job/jobByIndustries");  in footer area

my functon look likes

```
class Job extends MY_Controller {
```

public function jobByFunctionalarea() {

```
$this->load->model("job/job_model");
  $str = '';
  $groupby = "functionalareas.id";
  $this->job_model->table = "functionalareas";
  $join = array(array("jobs", "functionalareas.id = jobs.job_subcategory AND Date(jobs.apply_before) >= DATE(NOW())", "left"));
  $result = $this->job_model->get("functionalareas.*, count(jobs.job_subcategory) AS jobcount", "", $join, "", "", $groupby, false);
if ($result) {
       //var_dump($result);
       //die();
   foreach ($result as $row) {
       //var_dump($row);
        $str .= '<a href="job/category/'.$row->slug.'"  class="list-group-item">'.$row->name.'<span class="badge">';
        $str .= $row->jobcount;
        $str .= '</span></a>';
  }
  return $str;
}
```

}

}

it is work with home page and when my url goes to job/receptionist get following error in my conclusion the problem is on db driver not loading

A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/job.php

Line Number: 137

Comment: @mustang83 i have bellow could u draw out the problem

Comment: @mustang83 i post on original can u please figure out the problem

Comment: can you tell me which field in line no. 137?

Comment: $str .= '<a href="job/category/'.$row->slug.'"  class="list-group-item">'.$row->name.'<span class="badge">'; these line is in 137 boss @HardikRanpariya